# Snapping to the top when doing Svelte page transitions

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I've implemented a fading transition when changing pages in Svelte, and it works great. The only problem is that when you've scrolled down a bit on a page and click another link in the nav, it snaps the current page to the top before transitioning.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Here are my files

Pagefade.js

```
import { sineOut } from 'svelte/easing';

let timing = 600;

export const fadeIn = (_, { duration = timing, delay = timing }) => ({
    duration,
    delay,
    easing: sineOut,
    css: (t) => `opacity: ${t}`
});
export const fadeOut = (_, { duration = timing }) => ({
    duration,
    delay: 0,
    easing: sineOut,
    css: (t) => `opacity: ${t}`
})
```

index.svelte

```
<script>
    import { fadeIn, fadeOut } from '../components/pageFade';
</script>

<main in:fadeIn out:fadeOut>
    <section>
        <h1>This is Home</h1>
        <a href="/">Go back</a>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div>Hej hej</div>
    </section>
</main>
```

about.svelte

```
    import { fadeIn, fadeOut } from '../components/pageFade';
</script>

<main in:fadeIn out:fadeOut>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is contact</h1>
        <a href="/">Go back</a>
    </div>
</main>
```

The navbar is just an ul with a tags.
Thankful for any answers!

Answer (score 1):

SvelteKit default scroll behaviour can be disabled by adding the following to your components `<script/>`.

```
import { disableScrollHandling } from '$app/navigation';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
onMount(async () => {
    disableScrollHandling();
});
```

Tested wit your code.
Here are the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-disablescrollhandling).

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Will make sure to read up on the documentation, I'm quite new to Svelte but love it so far.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Also tried implementing "school-behavious: smooth" globally, which is also quite a cool effect

Comment: It doesn't work properly, when I navigate to the destiny page, the scroll is at the bottom of the page sometimes. This happens only if I scroll down the initial page and then I click the link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but only calling `disableScrollHandling` didn't quite work for me. It wasn't snapping to the top anymore, but still didn't go to the top of the clicked page after the transitioning. I fixed it with `afterNavigate` and `scrollTo`. The `scrollTo` has to be delayed with `setTimeOut`. The delay has to be lower than your page transition duration.

+layout.svelte

```
import { afterNavigate, disableScrollHandling } from '$app/navigation';

afterNavigate(() => {
    disableScrollHandling();
    setTimeout(() => {
        scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'instant' });
    }, 300);
});
```